# read from file and save to file with sqlplus on 1 line

Tags: sql, csv, command-line, sqlplus

I just got Oracle 12c installed and I'm trying to learn sqlplus. We have many scripts that use dbisql to connect to Sybase databases and retrieve data. The syntax of dbisql is very simple, but I can't figure out how to do the same thing in sqlplus. We just want to have sqlplus read a file with the SQL and output the results to a csv. I've read that you can do something like:

```
c:\scripts>sqlplus -L <username>/<pwd>@<tns service name> @"input_file.sql"
```

which will read in the contents of "input_file.sql" and execute it. But how can you save the results in a csv? Should that be done in the sql (like Sybase has the OUTPUT TO  command that we can then use MySQL's LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  command to load it) or SPOOL or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If practical, you could add spool commands to your script. Otherwise, you could run `sqlplus` interactively, manually spool, and manually run your script, and manually exit. You could also probably automate the manual method, but that is beyond the scope of this question.

You could specify file names at the command line like so:

```
sqlplus -L <username>/<pwd>@<tns service name> @"input_file.sql" outputfile
```

if, in your script, you opened your output file like so:

```
spool &1
```

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_three.htm#i1169374) for a reference.

Comment: I'm trying to get the input file and output file to all be on the same command-line to I can put it in a PHP script. The part I'm unclear on is more for the output part - does it need to be somewhere on the command line, or in the SQL input file.